# Reading a documents directory using FileSystemView returns blank when it deployed on the server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to save the excel data to  documents folder. First I am trying to print the documents folder path. It works fine When testing it locally in Eclipse but whenever I deploy it on the Apache Tomcat 7 server its returns nothing.

Is there any permission issue? Please let me know.

```
System.out.println(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you use?

Comment: System.out.println(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

if i get path from above code problem will be solved

Comment: I wouldn’t expect Swing classes to work inside Tomcat.  Why not use `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents")`?  (It’s actually more complicated than that, but I don’t know how much you care about high levels of robustness.)

Comment: Paths will not work for java 6 .we are using java 1.6 for building application.